# Display or dump out a bunch of file names from a Windows 7 directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, filenames, notepad

How can I get a text list or data dump of filenames from a Windows directory? I have the following folder set up:

```
[My Documents]
--SomeFileName.doc
--AnotherFileName.bmp
--AnotherMoreFileName.zip
--...
```

I want to get all the file names of the files that are inside the folder (My Documents) in just one process, and make the filenames as a list that I can copy to Notepad.

Currently my process is to hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to highlight the filename of the file and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and paste it into Notepad, then stack it to the list. I want to be able to get those filenames in a fast and easy way.

I want to avoid any external software if possible; I just want to utilize the software that is installed on my laptop (Office and Windows XP, though Vista or Windows 7 wouldn't be too bad to know).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open command prompt.

```
cd %homedrive%%homepath%\My Documents

dir /b > filenames.txt
```

`filenames.txt` will contain a list of all your files.

Comment: @Pennf0lio you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Open powershell and type the following:

```
PS> cd "~\My Documents"
PS> ls | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer)} | foreach-object {add-content -path filelist.txt -value $_.name}
```

What happens here is you `ls` (list) all the files in the directory and send that list through a filter that removes directories (where-object is not a container).  Then you send the filtered list to a loop that adds the file names to your txt file one at a time.  `$_` represents an object in the list.

You can do all kinds of other cool stuff with this like adding `-recurse` onto the ls command, which would give you all files in all directories under the current directory.

You can replace `$_.name` with `$_.fullName` to get the full path, or `$_.Extension` for the extension.  See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for the fileinfo class in msdn to see all the cool stuff you can do with a fileinfo object.